Качество кода, архитектуры. Service and Repository pattern. PHP & Laravel
Стремлюсь к очень качественному коду, посоветоваться не с кем. Вычитал очень много про архитектуру и пришел к этому (Пример на PHP Laravel)
Middleware - Прослойка запроса, проверка аутентификации и подобного, если это необходимо
FormRequest - Тут мы делаем валидацию запроса(Если это не GET)
Controller - тут мы принимаем запрос, делаем валидацию, если FormRequest не предусмотрен, отдаем это всё в Service и затем отдаём ответ
Service - Тут вся бизнес логика, обращение к Repository
ServiceInterface - интерфейс для нашего Service, для гибкости кода
Repository - логика обращения к базе данных, модели, все запросы и т д
RepositoryInterface - интерфейс для Repository, так же для гибкости
Затем мы регистрируем наши интерфейсы и их реализацию в ServiceProvider и работаем по такой архитектуре.
Хотел спросить - всё ли верно, не излишне ли, стоит ли добавить какой то шаг или же убрать. Спасибо

Разве в доках по ларке не указана структура папок для проектов?

А вообще, на текущий вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ. Разных видов архитектур достаточно много. И разные люди следуют разным подходам.....................
"не излишне ли, стоит ли добавить какой то шаг или же убрать" --- это может зависеть от проекта, от его масштаба, размаха и целей. Так что вы можете взять текущую структуру как некую исходную точку, а дальше его развивать в зависимости от проектов

Я бы добавил лишь использование папок в Http/Requests, к примеру у вас есть роуты для авторизации  /auth и роуты для работы с файлами /files, тогда можно создать папки Http/Requests/Auth и Http/Requests/Files
